# Pooling LDAP connections with custom socket factory

Tags: java, sockets, ldap, jndi, connection-pooling

My Java web application is using an LDAP backend for authentication / authorization. I am currently using a custom socket factory, and want to enable connection pooling for performance reasons.

The confusion starts.

According to the standard JNDI tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/config.html), *A Context instance cannot use a pooled connection if it has its "java.naming.ldap.factory.socket" property set to a custom socket factory class*.

However, according to the official (Java 6) JNDI documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html#pooling), *Pooling of connections from a custom socket factory is allowed when java.naming.ldap.factory.socket  environment property is set. For the custom socket factory to be pooled the socket factory class must implement the Comparator interface.*

Encouraging. What I have done so far:

- my custom socketfactory implements `Comparator<SocketFactory>` with a simple comparison of host+port
- when creating my `LdapContext`, I do `env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "portal.ldap.util.PortalSocketFactory")` and `env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true")`
- my Tomcat server is started with `-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.initsize=10 -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize=20 -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize=10 -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=300000 -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol="plain ssl" -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug="all"`

Next, a test. I connect to the application, it connects to the LDAP server, and behold - a connection pool is created. Clearly, my custom socketfactory is accepted:

```
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool@26cd2192 {}.get(): 172.17.2.91:636:ssl::portal.ldap.util.PortalSocketFactory:cn=PortalProxy,ou=sa,o=config
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool@26cd2192 {}.size: 0
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool@26cd2192 {}.get(): creating new connections list for 172.17.2.91:636:ssl::portal.ldap.util.PortalSocketFactory:cn=PortalProxy,ou=sa,o=config
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@65fe28a7.init size=10; size: 0
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@65fe28a7.max size=20; size: 0
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@65fe28a7.preferred size=10; size: 0
Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@127e942f[172.17.2.91:636]
<snip>
Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@3c7038b9[172.17.2.91:636]
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool@26cd2192 {172.17.2.91:636:ssl::portal.ldap.util.PortalSocketFactory:cn=PortalProxy,ou=sa,o=config=com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.ConnectionsRef@6b9c18ae}.get(): size after: 1
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@65fe28a7.get(): before; size: 10
ConnectionDesc.tryUse() com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@127e942f idle
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@65fe28a7.get(): use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@127e942f; size: 10
Use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@127e942f
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@65fe28a7.get(): after; size: 10
```

**BUT** you guessed it, something's rotten. Now, every time the application connects, *a new pool is instantiated!* I can see that the connections are actually pooled, because after the configured 300 seconds, they expire and are removed from the pool:

```
ConnectionDesc.expire(): not expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@e6c7a64 idle
ConnectionDesc.expire(): expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@39579371 idle
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@13a9192b.expire(): removing com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@39579371 expired; size: 10
Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@39579371 expired
ConnectionDesc.expire(): expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@2ada52a1 idle
com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@13a9192b.expire(): removing com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@2ada52a1 expired; size: 9
Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@2ada52a1 expired
<and so on>
```

**Help!** Am I missing some small detail? Has anyone succeeded in getting this to work?

Comment: On a hunch, I have added a debug println() in my socketfactory's `compare()` method, and ... *it is never called by the `LdapPoolManager`* !!

Comment: It's strange that they specified Comparator and not Comparable. It would make a lot more sense for a socket factory object to compareTo() itself rather than to compare two different objects, one of which is presumably always itself.

Comment: Agreed. As I understood it (from a post that I cannot find anymore) a new socketfactory (of the custom class) is created that performs the comparison. Seems somewhat dubious.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you move to a current LDAP API. many will have all the pooling classes already provided. -jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [actual code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/ldap/ClientId.java#l194) that does the comparison you'll see that it's definitely a bug. It expects `Comparator<String>` rather than `Comparator<SocketFactory>`. **classnames** of the factories are being passed, not the factories themselves. At a runtime `ClassCastException` is swallowed and [`false` is returned](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/ldap/ClientId.java#l201). That's why you cannot see your "debug println()" from the `compare` method -- it's never executed.

Comment: It had not come to mind to actually check the java source code. Just checked and it works when I use `Comparator<String>` ! Now the only drawback is, I have to *assume* that pooled connections of the same class have the same characteristics. So that would be a bug, yes. Thanks a lot for clearing this up!

Comment: On a side note: where would I log this as a bug? Any pointers?

Comment: @mvreijn Next time you see something like this you can log it here: http://bugs.java.com
But this time (if you don't mind) I will save our time and create an issue directly here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net

Comment: _I have to assume that pooled connections of the same class have the same characteristics_

You mean of the same `Class<T>` where `T extends SocketFactory`, right? If that's true, than would it be different if you used comparison by instance of `T` rather than by `Class<T>`? I mean that the general assumption (by design) is that given any 2 instances of `? extends SocketFactory` we can tell whether we can use connections created by them interchangeably.

Comment: *You mean of the same `Class<T>` where `T extends SocketFactory`, right?* Yes, but wouldn't the connections have to be to the same server/port combination to be truly interchangeable? Or is that managed elsewhere?

Comment: @mvreijn Don't worry, server/port combination is managed. Unfortunately, it's not that clear from documentation. Have a look [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/ldap/pool/Pool.java#l152) and [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/ldap/ClientId.java#l126). `ClientId` takes care of these things in `equals`. Instances of `ClientId` are used as keys in `Pool`'s `Map`.